# Best practice to avoid or refactor casting base type to derived class

Tags: refactoring, type-casting

I have an example about design patterns that demonstrates the adapter pattern.
But I see casting to derived class here. That is not very good.
If I meet such code in my practice, what is the best way to refactor it?
Or what principles should I follow to avoid such situation?

```
public class SqlServerLogSaverAdapter : ILogSaver
{
    private readonly SqlServerLogSaver _sqlServerLogSaver = new SqlServerLogSaver();
    public void Save(LogEntry logEntry)
    {
        var simpleEntry = logEntry as SimpleLogEntry;
        if (simpleEntry != null)
        {
            _sqlServerLogSaver.Save(simpleEntry.EntryDateTime,
                simpleEntry.Severity.ToString(),
                simpleEntry.Message);
            return;
        }
        var exceptionEntry = (ExceptionLogEntry)logEntry;
        _sqlServerLogSaver.SaveException(exceptionEntry.EntryDateTime, 
                exceptionEntry.Message,
                exceptionEntry.Exception);
    }
}
```

ps. May be visitor pattern solves it but I'm not sure.

Comment: As I see single negative score I've the question "why"? (To take into account it in future)

Comment: I would expect the Save method to work correctly for all types of `LogEntry` objects. Why can't it?

Comment: I didn't comprehend your question completely. So far Jules answered in correct way I suppose.

Comment: As this is a question on how to refactor working, but ugly, code, you should post it to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), rather than here.

Comment: David, thank you. I didn't know such possibility.

Comment: If you post this to Code Review @VitalyMosin, try to use a title that describes what the code does. Otherwise, the site would fill up with titles identical to this one.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to follow [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles. Specifically, code should depend on interfaces, not implementation details.

The problem here is that your LogSaver depends on a particular concrete implementation of LogEntry. The solution is have LogSaver depend on a common interface instead. In this example I name that interface `ISaveableLogEntry`.

```
public interface ISaveableLogEntry
{
    DateTime EntryDateTime { get; set; }
    String   TextToSave { get; }
}

public class SimpleLogEntry : ISaveableLogEntry
{
    public DateTime EntryDateTime { get; set; }
    public String Severity { get; set; }
    public String Message { get; set; }
    public String TextToSave 
    {
        get { return Severity + " " + Message; }
    }
}

public class ExceptionLogEntry : ISaveableLogEntry
{
    public DateTime EntryDateTime {get; set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
    public String TextToSave 
    {
        get { return this.Exception.Message + " " + this.Exception.StackTrace; }
    }
}

public class SqlServerLogSaverAdapter : ILogSaver
{
    private readonly SqlServerLogSaver _sqlServerLogSaver = new SqlServerLogSaver();

    public void Save(LogEntry logEntry)
    {
        ISaveableLogEntry e = logEntry as ISaveableLogEntry;
        if (e == null) return;
        _sqlServerLogSaver.Save(e.EntryDateTime, e.TextToSave);
    }
}
```

With the above code you never need to cast from general to specific. You only need to cast from specific to general (to get the `ISaveableLogEntry` interface). If the cast fails, the entry can't be saved (which makes sense if the object is not a saveable log entry). Otherwise, there is only one code path for saving it, since each SaveableLogEntry knows what needs to be saved.

As a David pointed out, if you're willing to modify the prototype of `SqlServerLogSaverAdapter.Save()` then you can even avoid all casting by changing it to

```
public void Save(ISaveableLogEntry logEntry)
```

...and filtering the list before you call it.  Easy to do with LINQ:

```
foreach (ISaveableLogEntry logEntry in _logEntryList.OfType<ISaveableLogEntry>())
{
    logAdapter.Save(logEntry);
}
```

Comment: The use of a `LogEntry` parameter, which you then cast to `ISaveableLogEntry` is odd. Why not just make the parameter, `ISaveableLogEntry`? Also, `TextToSave` isn't a good choice of name IMO, as it's making assumptions over how it'll be used. Something like `LogDescription` might be better. Aside from that, this is a very good answer that shows the power of polymorphism when used well.

Comment: Good point about the cast, I edited my answer.  As for `TextToSave`, I wanted to make a relatively simple example.  If I were to code this I'd probably expose loggable text as a `string[]` so that the logger could decide how to concatenate them, and give it a totally different name, like `LoggableContent` or something.

Comment: Thank you, but what if it's not enough to have single Save realization in _sqlServerLogSaver. if I need to save record to different db-tables?

Comment: You write another implementation of `Save`, in a class that implements `ILogSaver`, that also accepts an `ISaveableLogEntry` as an argument, then register the class in your composition root. Where is the issue?

Comment: No doubt I could add new realization of ILogSaver (f.ex. OracleLogSaverAdapter ) to save to other storage. But if i need different realization (simple logs save to one table and exception to another one) of _sqlServerLogSaver.Save?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the interface definition of `ILogSaver` is wrong: when you have to handle `SimpleLogEntry` different from `ExceptionLogEntry`, you need two distinct functions in the interface instead of the single `Save` function.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put, any code that works only with one type should be part of that type, rather than a client.  Clients shouldn't care what particular subtype of an abstract base or interface they receive.  So, for your specific example, I would refactor it like this:

```
public class SqlServerLogSaverAdapter : ILogSaver
{
    private readonly SqlServerLogSaver _sqlServerLogSaver =
    new SqlServerLogSaver();
    public void Save(LogEntry logEntry)
    {
        logEntry.saveTo(_sqlServerLogSaver);
    }
}

// ... in LogEntry
    abstract void saveTo(SqlServerLogSaver saver);

// ... in SimpleLogEntry

    void saveTo(SqlServerLogSaver  _sqlServerLogSaver)
    {
            _sqlServerLogSaver.Save(EntryDateTime,
                Severity.ToString(),
                Message);
    }


    //  in ExceptionLogEntry...

    void saveTo(SqlServerLogSaver  _sqlServerLogSaver)
    {
        _sqlServerLogSaver.SaveException(EntryDateTime, Message,
                                         Exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Simply put, any code that works only with one type should be part of that type...*". I completely disagree. Your code now couples log entries to a persistence mechanism. This is in direct violation of the single responsibility principle.

Answer (score -2):

Since the method will fail if anything else that an `ExceptionLogEntry` object is passed the methods parameter should be of type `ExceptionLogEntry` so that the caller is aware of this dependency and no cast would be needed.

Comment: The code also works if the type is `SimpleLogEntry`.

Comment: @Jules I'd expect a `ClassCastException` at `varexceptionEntry = (ExceptionLogEntry)logEntry;`

Comment: There's an early return inside the `if` statement above that prevents it when the type is `SimpleLogEntry`.

Comment: "*Since the method will fail if anything else that an `ExceptionLogEntry` object is passed..*." This statement is incorrect. It works for `SimpleLogEntry` too.